# How to find usages of ONE implementation of an interface's method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project with hundreds of implementations of an interface. I'd like to find the usages of a method in just ONE implementation of that interface. Intellij (and Eclipse) both show me all usages of that method in all of the implementations - hundreds of them.

I highlight the method in one implementation of the interface, right-click and select "find usages", and it shows me all usages of that method in all implementations.

None of the usage options in Intellij seem to get me just one implementation.

```
public interface Dog {
    void bark(int volume);
}
public class Lab implements Dog {
    public void bark(int volume) {
        System.out.println("woof");
    }
}
public class Collie implements Dog {
    public void bark(int volume) {
        System.out.println("woof");
    }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog onyx = new Lab();
        Dog lassie = new Collie();


        onyx.bark(50);
        lassie.bark(20);
    }
}
```

If I highlight the Lab bark method, click show usages, I want to just see the onyx.bark(50) line in main.java, not both bark usages in main.java.

I realize that if I use Lab onyx = new Lab() and Collie lassie = new Collie() in the main class, find references will work, but that's not how the project is written. Maybe there's no way for the IDE to determine the implementing class when the type is the interface, but it sure would be useful.

Comment: Awesome question.  I usually step through the debugger to find out what implementation is being used at that time, but there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Well, the point of interfaces is to be able to exchange one implementation for another at runtime. Your example is quite trivial and it might seem as if the IDE should be able to "know" the actual type of `onyx` and `lassie` but think of a more complex scenario: what if some library, reflection code etc. would change those references? How would the IDE know which would be called at runtime? It's quite a hard if not impossible task (at least for arbitrary code) so the IDE will show you all usages that _could_ end up calling that single implementation.

Comment: To illustrate Thomas’s point:  imagine a method `public static void barkTwice(Dog dog)`.  How would an IDE know which implementation is being passed as an argument?

Comment: Yes - I couldn't think of a way that the IDE could know what the type is at runtime, but I thought maybe it could guess based on the way it was assigned in main.  I suppose I could search for instances of "= new Lab()" or of the constructor itself, but the real project I'm working with uses spring - so there aren't any obvious constructors used. Searching through items.xml should work, but it's still not easy.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, the implementation being used is determined at runtime, so Intellij can't limit usage results to one implementation. However, Intellij support suggested creating a custom scope to limit the usage search. That helps a bit, although creating a scope requires that you know the general area where you usage is, which is maybe what you were doing the usage search for in the first place. In my case, I could create a scope that only includes the code our company has made to the project. That reduced the results from 500+ to about 80.

To create a custom scope in Intellij, select File-settings-appearance & behavior-Scopes. Click the plus sign in the middle of the dialog box, select local or shared, and give it a name. In the right half of the dialog box, you can include/exclude/include recursively/exclude recursively libraries, packages etc.

Then when you do your find usages (or other searches) click the gear icon in the results and select your new scope in the drop down list.

Comment: could you link where "company said"? I would like to read full reasoning...  In my opinion IDEA does not have only (compiled, type-erased) "classes", but IDEA have "sources" as well. So, it should be doable ...

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar case, where I've to find the usage of external library, say for eg:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

in my `Module:app` only. So, for this, go to

`1. Project` in the left tab of android studio > `Android` view > Right Click `app` directory > `Analyze` > `Analyaze Dependencies` > In the pop up window, select `Directory` only > Click `OK`.

Then `Dependency Viewer` Tab will open. Select where to search in left tree. For that, I click `app` in left tree. Then in the right tree, I have to select the External library, that I'm looking for. For that,

Open `External Dependencies` > Click `com/android/volley`.

Then at the bottom of both left and right trees, I can see all the usages of the external library in my `Module:app`.

Hope it helps...